# Schrödinger equation in 1D - Potential changes over vanishingly small regions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation

my curiosity has been aroused by the behaviour of the solution of the 1D Schrödinger equation for piecewise constant potentials, where one of the region over which the potential equals a certain constant is sent to zero.
I wondered if the solution of the equation
$$ \Psi '' = (E - V(x)) \Psi$$for the potential 
$$V(x) = \left\{
  \begin{array}{lr}
    \infty & : x < 0 \\
    0   &  : 0 \ge x \ge L \\
    V_0    &  : x > L
  \end{array}
\right.
$$
 converges continuously, as $L$ is sent to zero to the solution of the same equation, this time considering the potential
$$V(x) = \left\{
  \begin{array}{lr}
    \infty & : x < 0 \\
    V_0    &  : x > 0
  \end{array}
\right.
$$
The solution of the equation with the first potential, in the  case $E<V_0$  equals

$$V(x) = \left\{
  \begin{array}{lr}
    0 & : x < 0 \\
    A sin(kx)   &  : 0 \ge x \ge L \\
    (Ae^{-\alpha L} sin(kL))e^{-\alpha x}    &  : x > L
  \end{array}
\right.
$$ where $\alpha$ and $k$ depend on the value $E - V(x)$.

As the length $L$ is sent to zero, the term $(Ae^{-\alpha L} sin(kL))$ also goes to zero: I have though checked that, in order for the solution to be normalised, $A$ diverges in such a way that the limit is continuous (although one needs to know about the normalisation condition, if I had looked at the problem purely mathematically I would have never though about sending a solution constant to diverge...)
As $L$ goes to zero, the solution converges to the textbook case unilateral/infinite barrier (second potential), with a vertical shift $V_0$ inconsequential to the solution.

Is this a general feature of piecewise constant potentials, or even, more general, potentials? It certainly makes sense to me if I think at linear differential equations: it is the physical aspect that bothers me.
Thanks a lot